# Estimate diffuse and direct component from global irradiance

Tags: pvlib, solar

I am looking to separate the diffuse and direct component of global irradiance and found the Erbs model to do this in pvlib (see [pvlib.irradiance.erbs](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.irradiance.erbs.html)) however, I am getting very strange results. I would expect the Direct Normal Irradiance (DNI) to be lower than the Global Horizontal Irradiance (GHI); or am I missing something? Values of GHI are not above 800 W m^2 for these days.

[image]

---

EDIT: As per Cliff H advice, I have limited the solar zenith to less than 85 arc degrees; the results have improved however, there are large spikes in DNI values that do not appear very reasonable, e.g. start of 07-16.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNI > GHI is common at low solar elevation. GHI decreases much faster than DNI as solar elevation decreases. For example, think of a clear day with the sun right near the horizon. DNI will large because it's measured on a plane normal to the sun vector, but GHI will be near zero.

The values of DNI that are much greater than 1000 W/m2 are likely at very high zenith, since the Erbs model basically divides by cos(zenith).  In practice, I limit using decomposition models like Erbs to zenith<85 degrees, to avoid the non-physical results.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have limited the zenith to < 85 arc degrees. This has definitely improved the results however, I still get funny artefacts.

Comment: The results appear credible to me. The Erbs model is estimating the diffuse component of GHI, and returns DNI by a closure calculation, i.e., DNI = (GHI - DHI) / cos(Z). The empirical equation that obtains DHI from GHI is a fit through a fairly broad scatter of data, so it should be regarded as one of many possible values of DHI that correspond to the observed GHI value.

Comment: Thanks. I did not consider that DNI assumes the surface perpendicular to the rays. As this is slightly different, I have asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372519/how-to-estimate-dni-and-dhi-for-a-horizontal-surface-from-ghi) on how to estimate DNI and DHI for a horizontal surface from GHI.

Comment: @Kievit could you share how did you limit the solar zenith to < 85 arc degrees? I have an issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775990/python-pvlib-error-erbs-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-min-cos-zenith