# How to estimate direct horizontal irradiance from GHI

Tags: pvlib, solar

The Erbs function in pvlib (see [pvlib.irradiance.erbs](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.irradiance.erbs.html)) can be used to estimate the direct normal irradiance (DNI) and diffuse horizontal irradiance (DHI) from global horizontal irradiance (GHI) however, where DHI is for a horizontal surface, DNI is for a surface perpendicular to the rays, not a horizontal one. How can I estimate the direct horizontal irradiance given GHI? For example, this may be the case where one wants to separate the diffuse and direct component from a measurement of GHI for the same horizontal surface. Is it reasonable to use the Erbs model, compute DHI, and subtract DHI from GHI? I.e. `Direct horizontal irradiance = GHI - DHI`?

Comment: I don't fully understand what quantities you're starting with. The question title is "How to estimate DNI and DHI for a horizontal surface from GHI" but your equation for DNI projected into the horizontal plane presumes knowledge of DHI.

Comment: I think I clarified the question. In other words, I have a fixed radiometer installed on a mast that receives GHI and would like to estimate the direct and diffuse components for the same horizontal surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it reasonable to use the Erbs model, compute DHI, and subtract DHI from GHI? I.e. Direct horizontal irradiance = GHI - DHI?

Yes.