# Python PVLIB error 'erbs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_cos_zenith''

Tags: pvlib

I run the following code to estimate DNI and DHI from GHI using the Erbs model available in Sandia's PVLIB.

The original code as [here](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.irradiance.erbs.html) is:

`pvlib.irradiance.erbs(ghi, zenith, datetime_or_doy, min_cos_zenith=0.065, max_zenith=87)`

My code is:

`df= pvlib.irradiance.erbs(df.ghi, sun.zenith, df.index, min_cos_zenith=0.065, max_zenith=85)`

But my code returns `erbs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_cos_zenith'`. Any help is appreciated.

I use:
Python 3.7.3
PVLIB 0.6.1
Pandas 0.24.2

EDIT:
Maybe the solution is to upgrade to PVLIB v0.6.2. But, how to upgrade it. In my machine, none of the following works: `pip install pvlib`, `pip install --upgrade pvlib`, `pip install pvliv ==0.6.2`

Comment: for future reference: https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/issues/689#issuecomment-485286373

Answer (score 1):

Just call the function without the new (optional) arguments:

`df= pvlib.irradiance.erbs(df.ghi, sun.zenith, df.index)`

Comment: Thanks, but without new arguments, the resulted DHI become strange when plotted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53269553/estimate-diffuse-and-direct-component-from-global-irradiance

Comment: Well, if you got that far then the problem you asked about is solved.  If you have a question about your strange plot, then best thing would be to post another question about that--with an image of your strange plot and the code used to produce it.

Answer (score 0):

AS of 2019-04-28 the pvlib version was v0.6.1 which does not yet have the `min_cos_zenith` optional argument for [`erbs()`](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.1/generated/pvlib.irradiance.erbs.html#pvlib.irradiance.erbs). As [Will Holmgren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802993/will-holmgren) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775990/python-pvlib-error-erbs-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-min-cos-zenith#comment98244938_55775990), a workaround in the meantime would be to install the latest master from GitHub using [pip vcs support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support):

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python.git@master#egg=pvlib
```